# How to divide cards to 3 parts?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose a deck have 13 cards, I want to divide them to 3 parts. The 1st part has 3 cards and both of the 2nd and 3rd part have 5 cards. There are many combinations.

a method called `get_score(cards)` is used to calculate the score of cards, and total_score is the summarise of 3 parts of cards(total_score = get_score(cards1)+get_score(cards2)+get_score(cards3).

How to get the card combinations with top total_score? Get all possible combinations and calculate score, and sort the scores is a way, but it's too slow.

Comment: Depending on how `get_score` works, there might be useful heuristics to use. Without that information, you have to enumerate and test all the combinations. E.g., if you multiply card values that are in the same set, it would make sense to put all the high-values cards into one set, whereas if the score of each set is the highest card's score, you should distribute them.

Comment: `get_score` is very complicated.

Comment: BTW, not taking order into account, aren't there merely 72072 unique combinations? Should not be too much of a problem to test them all.

Comment: You can precalculate `get_score` for all possible subsets. There are `2^13` subsets in total.

Comment: @tobias_k `get_score` is complicated so execute 72072 times  is too slow.

Comment: @DAle Sounds a good idea.

Comment: There are only 1287 combinations of 5 cards and 286 combinations of 3 cards. You can precompute the scores of these piles. Then run through all possible combinations, without calling `get_score` again.

Comment: If you're creating a Chinese poker game, there's additional constraint -- the hands must be in increasing strength, front to back. So for each of the 286 three card hands, there's 126 ways of breaking the remaining 10 cards into two 5-card hands (and you don't get a choice of which is middle and which is back). And you discard many further combinations, since the middle must beat the back. I don't include code, but here's my blog post on CP: http://paulhankin.github.io/ChinesePoker/ ....

Comment: My own code adds another optimisation -- by keeping a "domination set" of hands found, one can discard any hand before scoring if it's worse in each three places than a previously found hand. That reduces the amount of scoring dramatically.

Comment: @PaulHankin Your blog really helped me, thank you.